# Can I clear memory after training the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote a script to get data from some API and train on the data obtained, the model trains perfectly and even predicted the end value with good accuracy but when I reach model number 6 or higher my script crashes and I have to reopen the IDE. I have a brave browser running playing music on youtube it also crashes and I get different errors every time stating that memory is not enough but I am training the model on a pretty good rig (specs CPU: i5 7400  GPU: GTX 1050 2GB  RAM: 20GB).

Below is my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=1000 , return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=1000 , return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1 ))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error' , metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

I got this error once in the IDE console part

> MemoryError : Unable to allocate 15.3 MiB for an array with shape
> (1000, 4000) and data type float32

another error I got as a pop-up notification

> DirectX function "device-> CreateBuffer(&dxDesc,&resourceData,
> &buffer-> m_buffer)" failed with E_OUTOFMEMORY ("Direct3D could not
> allocate sufficient memory to complete the call.") GPU:NVIDIA GeForce
> GTX 1050", Driver 45148

I have Nvidia inspector running without overclocking and it also crashes and outputs an error basically stating that it also crashed without any other useful piece of information.

Is there anything I can do to clear the memory or any work around this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce your batch size. Right now you have an 2D array `1000x4000` of 4 bytes per, resulting in 16 megabytes per input. With 2GB RAM on your GPU you can stuff a maximum batch size of `128`.

EDIT: I think I misread your question. To clear your GPU you need to use `tf.keras.backend.clear_session`.

Comment: i tried adding `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` but it keeps crashing and i tried changing the units for to 128 for each LSTM layer but no improvement

Comment: A maximum batch size of 128 is assuming your GPU isn't loaded with anything else. I'd recommend using batches of 64 or lower, considering mini-batches has been seen to have improved performances.